# Bootstrap javascript tab card

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use bootstrap's card/tab feature to create a tabulated card that has 3 tabs, each corresponding to it's own active 'card body'

My current code:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h2>Social Media</h2>      
      </div>
      <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#insta">Instagram</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#face">Facebook</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#twit">Twitter</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="insta">Instagram</div>
          <div id="face">Facebook</div>
          <div id="twit">Twitter</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END WIDGET 2 -->
    </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
});
});
```

Creates the card correctly, and it indeed shows the appropriate tab headers with their respective links.

What I'm trying to do is make it so that if the Instagram tab is active, it shows the text 'Instagram'. Same for the other 2. Currently they are just inactive tabs and the main tab's body shows all three lines of text.

The javascript looks right but it's just not tabulating properly

Here's the codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKLJrm

Comment: To make single content at a time write in this format. <div class="card-body tab-content"><div id="insta" class="tab-pane active">Instagram</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to the use the appropriate markup for tabs with `tab-content` and `tab-pane` to make the tabs work: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior

**(no jquery is needed)**

https://www.codeply.com/go/p5Zm4JA5jb

```
  <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#insta">Instagram</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#face">Facebook</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#twit">Twitter</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content card-body">
            <div id="insta" class="tab-pane active">Instagram</div>
            <div id="face" class="tab-pane">Facebook</div>
            <div id="twit" class="tab-pane">Twitter</div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Notice both the `nav-link` and `tab-pane` have the `active` item set.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.nav-item a').on('click', function(e){
var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');
// Show/Hide Tabs
$('.tab-content ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
// Change/remove current tab to active
$(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

```css
li.nav-item.active a {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: none
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="page-header">
            <h2>Social Media</h2>      
          </div>
          <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" id="myTabs">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#insta">Instagram</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#face">Facebook</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#twit">Twitter</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body tab-content">
              <div id="insta" class="tab-pane active">Instagram</div>
              <div id="face" class="tab-pane">Facebook</div>
              <div id="twit" class="tab-pane">Twitter</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- END WIDGET 2 -->
        </div>
```